# Format Number with Commas and Cents while typing it in Textbox and Compute It

Tags: vb.net

Good Morning Everyone, I hope you can help me with my problem. Please

Lets say I have a Group of `Textboxes` that will compute for a Certain Amount (No Currency Sign)

My 1st Question is How can I input proper number in `Textbox`? like if I input `22` then while typing that the output should be `22.00` and If I put something like `1164.25` that output would be like this 1,164.25 the `.25` is the Decimal like it was a Cent(Regardless of what I want to Type), I hope you get me. You know proper tying of a number with commas and cents.

I hope I can achieve this using `Keyprees` and `Textchanged`

and here is My Second Question lets say Im done inputting the number in the Textbox, Lets say the Name of textbox is `GrandTotal.text`

and I have a `NumericUpdown1.Value`,`VatAmount.Text` and `TotalAmount.Text`

The task of `NumericUpdown1.Value` is for Percent.

Here is my 2nd Question: How can I compute for a percentage of a number? Lets Say like this.

```
__________________________________________________________
|VatAmount.Text|=|NumericUpDown1.Value|of|GrandTotal.Text|
----------------------------------------------------------
|11.655        |=|1 Percent           |of|1165.5         |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Final Output should be like this:

```
_____________________________________________________
|TotalAmount.Text|=|GrandTotal.Text|+|VatAmount.Text|
-----------------------------------------------------
|1177.155        |=|1165.5         |+|11.655        |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

TYSM For Future Help

Comment: It's not really practical to reformat as you type.  Your best bet is to just let the user enter whatever number they want and then format when they leave the control.

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time.  If you have a second question then ask it in a second post.

Comment: Consider all the things a user can type as they go, including typos.  You will have an enormous amount of error checking involved to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the textbox to currenc can be done in the keypress event like so:
Also be aware that different locations use different deliminaters "," or "."

```
 Private Sub TextBox11_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox11.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        Me.TextBox11.Text = CDec(TextBox11.Text).ToString("C")
    End If
End Sub
```